# Why does Python IDLE echo None as empty instead of string 'None' (the value of repr(None))?

Tags: python, python-idle

According to [official doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html#user-output-in-shell), "The `repr` function is used for interactive echo of expression values".

Basically, what you see in echo is equivalent to `print(repr(*yourexpression*)`.

This seems to be true in most of cases, but `None` is exception.

```
>>> print(repr(1))
1
>>> 1
1
>>> print(repr('abc'))
'abc'
>>> 'abc'
'abc'
>>> print(repr(None))
None
>>> None
>>>
```

Comment: Another somewhat strange result here is that `print(repr(1))` prints `1` rather than `'1'`.  I find that strange, as `repr()` always returns a string value.  So even though `print` is printing a string value, it does not print the single quotes if the value of the string is numeric.

Comment: The REPL explicitly doesn't print `None`, Basically,y ou can imagine a `result = eval(expression)` then a `if result is not None: ... # print result`

Comment: @CryptoFool thats *always* how printing strings work... it prints *the contents of the string to the standard output device*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - I don't see that your comment explains the issue.  Isn't the "contents of a string" a string?  So then if it's appropriate to put quotes around one string value, why not all string values?  Can you find where this special behavior is explained in the Python docs, or alternatively, describe the printing process to explain why this behavior isn't a special case?

Comment: @CryptoFool no, take for example the string `s = "Foo"`, there are **no quotations marks in the string**. This isn't special at all. `print(s)` will print just `Foo`. However, if you `print(repr(s))` it will print `'Foo'`, because `repr(s) == "'Foo'"` which has single quotes (but no double quotes) in the string

Comment: in other words,  `repr(1) == '1'` but `'1' != "'1'"`

Comment: Ah, yeah!  That last thing did it for me.  So the missing piece in my thinking is that `repr('abc')` is `"'abc'"`.  That is, `repr` returns the contents of the string in **quotes**!.  That's what I was missing.  That fact explains it all and makes everything consistent.  Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: I also see that for any type X entered alone at the REPL prompt, the shell basically calls `print(repr(X))`. That's why typing `'abc'` prints `'abc'` (with the quotes).  `repr` is adding those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The read-eval-print-loop, or REPL, normally only prints non-`None` results. That prevents it from clogging up your output for functions that do things but otherwise return nothing.

This automagic output of results is unique to the REPL, this is not something Python does in the normal course of business (when running scripts, for example).

---

The actual method used combines a few things that happen in interactive mode. First, when compiling, the normal `POP_TOP` opcode (meant to simply remove the result) is replaced with `PRINT_EXPR` at the topmost level (code irrelevant to the immediate question, in all code snippets below, has been removed, and the code may also have been reformatted a little):

```c
static int compiler_visit_stmt_expr(struct compiler *c, expr_ty value) {
    if (c->c_interactive && c->c_nestlevel <= 1) {
        VISIT(c, expr, value);
        ADDOP(c, PRINT_EXPR);
        return 1;
    }
    VISIT(c, expr, value);
    ADDOP(c, POP_TOP);
    return 1;
}
```

---

Secondly, when interpreting, the `sys.displayhook` object, a function meant to display results in interactive mode, normally points to a function that will only print out values that are not `None`. It's called in the `ceval` code when processing the afore-mentioned `PRINT_EXPR` opcode:

```c
case TARGET(PRINT_EXPR): {
    PyObject *value = POP();
    PyObject *hook = _PySys_GetObjectId(&PyId_displayhook);
    res = PyObject_CallOneArg(hook, value);
}
```

The *default* hook looks something like this and you can see it simply returns without output if the value is `None`:

```c
static PyObject *sys_displayhook(PyObject *module, PyObject *o) {
    if (o == Py_None) {
        Py_RETURN_NONE;
    }
    if (PyFile_WriteObject(o, outf, 0) != 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

This hook actually allows you to change the default behaviour as desired, though the `FortyTwo` example below is somewhat, err ..., less than useful:

```py
>>> 1
1
>>> None

>>> def NonesAsWell(x):
...     print(x)
...
>>> sys.displayhook = NonesAsWell
>>> 1
1
>>> None
None

>>> def FortyTwo(x):
...     print(42)
...
>>> sys.displayhook = FortyTwo
>>> 1
42
>>> None
42
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the literal question "Why does the IDLE Shell display what it does when the user enters a statement?" is that the IDLE Shell is, with few exceptions, intended to display the same output as the Python REPL.  For the entries discussed here, it does.

Others have already answered the underlying question "Why does the Python REPL do what it does."